# When my Application Launch, Force Close Error Occur

Tags: android

While testing on my Galaxy Nexus, I exited the app via pressing the back button and  then when I launched the app again, only seconds later, it caused the app to FC and generate an error report. Can any one help me,it happened only on Glaxy Nexus. Is there any limitation on Nexus series devices to open connection ? Why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

```
finish_activity_delayed start Activity_NewsFeed.class
[ 12-21 19:43:11.567 13784:13795 I/ActivityManager ]
START u0 {flg=0x10000 cmp=com.platinumapps.facedroid/com.platinumapps.activities.Activity_NewsFeed (has extras)} from pid 2384
[ 12-21 19:43:11.622  2384:14125 E/CursorWindow ]
Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/com.platinumapps.facedroid/databases/db_facedroid' of size 2097152 due to error -24.
[ 12-21 19:43:11.677  2384:14125 W/dalvikvm ]
threadid=44: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411e8930)
[ 12-21 19:43:11.731  2384:14147 E/NativeCrypto ]
AppData::create pipe(2) failed: Too many open files
[ 12-21 19:43:11.755  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. 
[ 12-21 19:43:11.770  2384:14146 E/NativeCrypto ]
AppData::create pipe(2) failed: Too many open files
[ 12-21 19:43:11.833  2384: 2387 D/dalvikvm ]
GC_CONCURRENT freed 660K, 28% free 48158K/65972K, paused 14ms+22ms, total 189ms
[ 12-21 19:43:11.833  2384: 2384 D/dalvikvm ]
WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 154ms
[ 12-21 19:43:11.833  2384:14130 D/dalvikvm ]
WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 54ms
[ 12-21 19:43:11.841  2384:14125 D/dalvikvm ]
WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 59ms
[ 12-21 19:43:11.856  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:104)
[ 12-21 19:43:11.856  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
[ 12-21 19:43:11.856  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:139)
[ 12-21 19:43:11.856  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
[ 12-21 19:43:11.856  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at com.platinumapps.friendlist.BLL_Friendlist.isTableEmpty(BLL_Friendlist.java:719)
[ 12-21 19:43:11.950  2384:14147 E/NativeCrypto ]
AppData::create pipe(2) failed: Too many open files
[ 12-21 19:43:11.989  2384:14146 E/NativeCrypto ]
AppData::create pipe(2) failed: Too many open files
[ 12-21 19:43:12.028  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at com.platinumapps.activities.Activity_NewsFeed$1.run(Activity_NewsFeed.java:110)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.028  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.028  2384:14125 D/FlurryAgent ]
Error logged: uncaught
[ 12-21 19:43:12.028  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. 
[ 12-21 19:43:12.099 13784:13797 W/ActivityManager ]
Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41d4f110 u0 com.platinumapps.facedroid/com.platinumapps.activities.Splash_Activity}
[ 12-21 19:43:12.138  2384:14147 W/System.err ]
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unable to create application data
[ 12-21 19:43:12.169  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:104)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.169  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unable to create application data
[ 12-21 19:43:12.169  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.169  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:378)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.169  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.169  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:442)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:295)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:697)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:312)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14147 W/System.err ]
org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 D/AsynFacebookRunner ]
Unable to create application data
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 D/BaseRequestListener ]
Message:Unable to create application data Cause: null
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14147 W/System.err ]
    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:378)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14147 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14147 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14147 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:442)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14147 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14147 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14147 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14147 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14147 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unable to create application data
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:378)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:442)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:295)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:697)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14146 W/System.err ]
    at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:312)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14147 W/System.err ]
    at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:295)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14147 W/System.err ]
    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.requestRestApi(Facebook.java:708)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14147 W/System.err ]
    at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$3.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:370)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.184  2384:14147 E/stream   ]
Network Error:Unable to create application data
[ 12-21 19:43:12.231  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
[ 12-21 19:43:12.286  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:139)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.333  2384: 2384 I/Choreographer ]
Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[ 12-21 19:43:12.356 16084:16088 D/dalvikvm ]
GC_CONCURRENT freed 466K, 8% free 9497K/10232K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 29ms
[ 12-21 19:43:12.434  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.434  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at com.platinumapps.friendlist.BLL_Friendlist.isTableEmpty(BLL_Friendlist.java:719)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.544  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at com.platinumapps.activities.Activity_NewsFeed$1.run(Activity_NewsFeed.java:110)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.841  2384: 2458 D/dalvikvm ]
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1135K, 19% free 54019K/65972K, paused 221ms, total 221ms
[ 12-21 19:43:12.934  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.934  2384:14125 D/FlurryAgent ]
Error logged: uncaught
[ 12-21 19:43:12.934  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. 
[ 12-21 19:43:12.934  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:104)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.934  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
[ 12-21 19:43:12.942  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:139)
[ 12-21 19:43:13.036  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
[ 12-21 19:43:13.036  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at com.platinumapps.friendlist.BLL_Friendlist.isTableEmpty(BLL_Friendlist.java:719)
[ 12-21 19:43:13.036  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at com.platinumapps.activities.Activity_NewsFeed$1.run(Activity_NewsFeed.java:110)
[ 12-21 19:43:13.036  2384:14125 W/System.err ]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
[ 12-21 19:43:13.075  2384:14125 D/FlurryAgent ]
Error logged: uncaught
[ 12-21 19:43:13.099  2384:14125 E/ACRA     ]
ACRA caught a CursorWindowAllocationException exception for com.platinumapps.facedroid. Building repo
```

rt.

Comment: And how do you expect us to help with the information you have provided?

Comment: Please provide some code that is producing the error you get.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error is mainly caused by this issue

`AppData::create pipe(2) failed: Too many open files`

And this can happen in any case. For example

1. You are creating so many `HTTP connections` in your app.
2. Opening to many `files connection` from `internal` or `External` SD card'
3. or this can be combination of Some `data access by DB` + `file writer object` and `HTTP connections`.

**Solution**

Try to limit your network operation like use `thread pool` and put a limit of `max 5` connections at time and also if doing some file operations then try to serialize them. For db `close all open connections` whenever you exit.

Answer (score 1):

this may be the reason:

```
[ 12-21 19:43:11.731  2384:14147 E/NativeCrypto ] AppData::create pipe(2) failed: Too many open files
```

Your app probably does not close resources it is using.