# Android Sqlite read error

Tags: android, sqlite

It displays 70% of the records , But others 30% records failed to display with 
Error:

> Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/com.backapp_inter/databases/backapp' of size 4194304 due to error -12."

Here's my code:

```
package com.backapp_inter.db;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;


public class dbquery {
ContentResolver cr;
Context c;
DatabaseHelper dh;
SQLiteDatabase db;
    public dbquery(ContentResolver cr,Context c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.cr=cr;
        this.c=c;
        dh=new DatabaseHelper(c);
        db=dh.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

Here is the logic to list contact name, its Emails and numbers.

```
    public void process(){


        Cursor name = db.query("name", new String[]{"ID","name"}, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(name.moveToFirst()){
            Log.e("Total Name",""+name.getCount());

            while(!name.isAfterLast()) {    
                Log.e("Name",name.getString(1));
                givemeemail(name.getInt(name.getColumnIndex("ID")));
        //      givemephone(name.getInt(name.getColumnIndex("ID")));
                name.moveToNext();
            }
        }

    name=null;
    }
    public void givemeemail(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            Log.v("TRACK #00","givemeemail");
            Cursor email = db.query("email", new String[]{"edata","etype"}, "fID=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(i)},null, null, null); 
//          Log.e("Edata",email.getColumnIndex("edata")+"");
//          Log.e("Etype",email.getColumnIndex("etype")+"");
            if(email.moveToFirst()){
                while(!email.isAfterLast()) {   
                    Log.e("Email",email.getString(0));
                    Log.e("Email Type",email.getString(1));

                    email.moveToNext();
                }

            }
            email=null;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            if(e!=null){
                Log.v("Number Parse Exception","dbquery.java");
            }
        }

    }
    public void givemephone(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            Log.v("TRACK #00","givemephone");
            Cursor phone = db.query("phone", new String[]{"pdata","ptype"}, "fID=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(i)},null, null, null); 

            if(phone.moveToFirst()){
                while(!phone.isAfterLast()) {   
                    Log.e("Phone",phone.getString(0));
                    Log.e("Phone Type",phone.getString(1));

                    phone.moveToNext();
                }
            }
        phone=null;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            if(e!=null){
                Log.v("Number Parse Exception","dbquery.java");
            }
        }

    }
}


Logcat :

01-24 17:09:41.601: E/Name(32656): nilu_160488@yahoo.com
01-24 17:09:41.601: V/TRACK #00(32656): givemeemail
01-24 17:09:41.601: E/Email(32656): nilu_160488@yahoo.com
01-24 17:09:41.601: E/Email Type(32656): Home
01-24 17:09:41.601: E/Name(32656): scope4it
01-24 17:09:41.601: V/TRACK #00(32656): givemeemail
01-24 17:09:41.601: E/CursorWindow(32656): Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/com.backapp_inter/databases/backapp' of size 4194304 due to error -12.
01-24 17:09:41.611: V/Number Parse Exception(32656): Email + dbquery.java
01-24 17:09:41.611: E/Name(32656): Suthar Ila
01-24 17:09:41.611: V/TRACK #00(32656): givemeemail
01-24 17:09:41.611: E/CursorWindow(32656): Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/com.backapp_inter/databases/backapp' of size 4194304 due to error -12.
01-24 17:09:41.611: V/Number Parse Exception(32656): Email + dbquery.java
01-24 17:09:41.611: E/Name(32656): Chaitanya Prajapati
01-24 17:09:41.611: V/TRACK #00(32656): givemeemail
01-24 17:09:41.611: E/CursorWindow(32656): Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/com.backapp_inter/databases/backapp' of size 4194304 due to error -12.
01-24 17:09:41.611: V/Number Parse Exception(32656): Email + dbquery.java
01-24 17:09:41.611: E/Name(32656): piadolandia-unsubscribe@googlegroups.com
01-24 17:09:41.611: V/TRACK #00(32656): givemeemail
01-24 17:09:41.611: E/CursorWindow(32656): Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/com.backapp_inter/databases/backapp' of size 4194304 due to error -12.
01-24 17:09:41.611: V/Number Parse Exception(32656): Email + dbquery.java
01-24 17:09:41.611: E/Name(32656): Ahmed_recruiter+unsubscribe@googlegroups.com
01-24 17:09:41.611: V/TRACK #00(32656): givemeemail
01-24 17:09:41.611: E/CursorWindow(32656): Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/com.backapp_inter/databases/backapp' of size 4194304 due to error -12.
01-24 17:09:41.611: V/Number Parse Exception(32656): Email + dbquery.java
```

Comment: try [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989961/when-my-application-launch-force-close-error-occur)

Comment: Thanks. Bhavesh. But this does not solve my error -12

Comment: just to ask: why aren't you grabbing NAME, EMAIL, EMAIL_TYPE, PHONE in a single `select` query?

Comment: David M: Name, Email and Phone - all reside in different tables.Table name's ID is taken as foreign key to other email and phone tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always make sure you close your cursor, preferably in a finally block, just setting the reference to null doesn't release it's resources.

```
...
Cursor cursor = null;
try {
 ..open your cursor, run query, loop etc
} finally {
 if (cursor!=null) cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Masse: Thanks. It is Solved. Actually ,I was setting the cursors to "null". But making it null didnt release the resources. Your Approach Worked.